# Use Gridstack or gridster for widget layout?

Tags: layout, widget, gridster

I'm trying to choose a widget layout and I have come across:

gridstack: http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/

gridster: http://gridster.net/[enter link description here](http://gridster.net/)

Any one used these before who can share the pros and cons and features?

Comment: I think gridstack was built more with front-end frameworks in mind, like bootstrap or knockout js.  I hear it was inspired by gridster, but that's about all I know.

Answer (score 9):

[Gridster](https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js) is a great library built by [Ducksboard](https://ducksboard.com/) who were acquired some time back. At this time, to the best of my understanding, they have ceased development and the fork community is not very active.

[Gridstack](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) is an active project at this time. It's openly states it was inspired by Gridster and so should offer much the same functionality, if not all, in time. Gridstack is not a rebuild of Gridster, however, and aims to improve upon the concept. For example, it supports responsive layouts, [becoming a vertical stack of widgets on smaller format screens](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/&w=603&h=966&a=23).

Gridstack is the way to go if you're looking for a library like this these days.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Gridstack since .63 and like it very much. I built it using JQuery, and will be porting it to react soon. I would give this library a 9 out of ten.